# On automorphism  of   some finite 2-group of class nilpotency  two

Tags: finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite 2-group of nilpotency  class  two such that $\frac{G}{Z(G)}=\{Z(G), aZ(G), bZ(G), abZ(G)\}\simeq C_{2}\times C_{2}$. Then do there exist a non inner automorphism $\alpha$ of $G$ such that $\alpha(a)\neq a$, $\alpha(b)\neq b$ and $\alpha(ab)\neq ab$ ? 
For example this true for  $D_{8}$,  dihedral group of order 8, or $Q_{8}$, generalized quaternion group of order 8.

Comment: Could you say something about how you came across this question, because as written it looks like a homework question.

Comment: Derek Holt answered this question 2 hours ago at math.stackexchange: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/155023/669

Comment: Noah, it seems like it might not be homework, just yet another case (if you look at the OP's original question) of someone wanting information rather than thinking for themselves